# how to put a tooltip in a looping calendar

Tags: php, jquery

how can i put a tooltip in a specific date? Can someone please help me. I really need this

and how can i put a ajax so that my calendar doesn't refresh

This is my code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
Class CALEVENTS
{
    var $host;
    var $user;
    var $password;
    var $database;
    var $db=NULL;

    function CALEVENTS($host="",$user="",$password="",$database="")
    {
        $this->setInfo($host,$user,$password,$database);
    }

    function setInfo($host,$user,$password,$database)
    {
        $this->host=$host;
        $this->user=$user;
        $this->password=$password;
        $this->database=$database;
        //$this->db=new DB();
        //$this->db->open($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
        $this->db=mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
        mysql_select_db($this->database);
    }

    function drawCalendar()
    {
        $db_event=$this->db;

        if(isset($_GET['time']))
            $time=$_GET['time'];
        else
            $time=time();

        $today = getdate($time); 
        $mday = $today ['mday'];
        $mon  = $today ['mon'];   
        $year  = $today ['year'];  

        $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mon,1,$year);

        $today = getdate($time); 
        $wday  = $today ['wday'];  
        $year  = $today ['year'];  
        $weekday = $today ['weekday'];
        $month  = $today ['month'];
        $i= -$wday;
        $thisPage=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

        $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mon+1,0,$year);
        $lastDay=date('j',$time);

        $sql="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(eventDate,'%d') AS day,eventContent,eventTitle,eventID FROM events WHERE eventDate BETWEEN  '$year/$mon/01' AND '$year/$mon/31'";  
        //$db_event->query($sql);
        $result=mysql_query($sql,$db_event);
        $events=array();

        //while($row_event=$db_event->fetchObject())
        //  $events[intval($row_event->day)].=$row_event->eventContent."<br><br>";
        while($row_event=mysql_fetch_object($result))
            $events[intval($row_event->day)].=$row_event->eventTitle."<br>" .$row_event->eventContent;

        echo "<style>\n";
        echo ".event_cls {background-color: #b7c8ef; color:white; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; cursor: hand;}\n";
        echo " <div id='event' style='  left: 395px; top: 192px; color:black'></div></td> </tr> </table>\n";
        echo ".event_cls:hover {background-color:ced9f0;}";
        echo ".event_col:hover {background-color:ced9f0;}";
        echo ".event_head{background-color: #333b73; color:white; font-weight:bold;FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;FONT-SIZE: 12px;}\n";
        echo ".event_col{background-color:#e2e6ef; color:#000095; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;FONT-SIZE: 11px; height='75' width='75'}\n";
        echo ".event_link {TEXT-DECORATION: none; color:#0DB0FF;}\n";
        echo "</style>";
        echo "<table width='870' border='0' align='center' style='border-style:solid;border-width:1px;position:relative;top:15px;left:15px;' cellspacing='1'>\n";
        echo "<tr class='event_col' align='center'> \n";
        echo "<td height='75'><b><a href='$thisPage?time=".mktime(0, 0, 0, $mon-1,$mday,$year)."' title='Previous Month' class='event_link'><</a></b></td>\n";
        echo "<td colspan='5' class='event_col'> <b>$month $year</b></td>\n";
        echo "<td height='75'><b><a href='$thisPage?time=".mktime(0, 0, 0, $mon+1,$mday,$year)."' title='Next Month' class='event_link'>></a></b></td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";

        echo "<tr class='event_col' height='25''>\n";
        echo "<td align='center' height='75' width='75' class='event_head'>Sunday</td>\n";
        echo "<td align='center' height='75' width='75' class='event_head'>Monday</td>\n";
        echo "<td align='center' height='75' width='75' class='event_head'>Tuesday</td>\n";
        echo "<td align='center' height='75' width='75' class='event_head'>Wednesday</td>\n";
        echo "<td align='center' height='75' width='75' class='event_head'>Thursday</td>\n";
        echo "<td align='center' height='75' width='75' class='event_head'>Friday</td>\n";
        echo "<td align='center' height='75' width='75' class='event_head'>Saturday</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
        echo "<script>\n";
        foreach($events as $key => $value)
        echo "evnt$key=\"$value\"\n";

        echo "function showevent(day)\n";
        echo "{";
        echo "  evnt=eval('evnt'+day);\n";
        echo "  mydiv=document.getElementById('event');\n";
        echo "  mydiv.innerHTML=evnt\n";
        echo "}";

        echo "</script>\n";
        for($j=0;$j<6;$j++){ 
        echo "<tr> \n";
        for($k=0;$k<7;$k++){ 
        $i++;
        $cls="class='event_col'";
        if(array_key_exists($i,$events))
        $cls="class=event_cls onmouseover='showevent($i)'";
        echo "<td  height='75' $cls>\n";
        echo ($i>0&&$i<=$lastDay)?$i:'';
        echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>" ; }

        echo " <tr > <td colspan=8 >\n";
        echo " </td> </tr>    </table>\n";
        echo"<br/><div id='event' style=' z-index:1000; left: 395px; top: 192px; color:#000;'></div>";
    }?>
```

I really need help.. please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can set "id" to each "td" and then in javascript you can setAttribute "title" to some value.

Comment: can you cite some example please?